# web application with local webserver on client machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, webserver

I have simple web application built on html5 and RoR. It is simple application where user records his voice(html5 web audio) and then it is saved locally. Application won't be hosted on server instead it would be hosted on individual user machine. I need to develop some portable package like exe which will be run on Windows and Mac.

Is this possible? If yes, then what are the ways to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You might find some useful info [here](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/distributingrubyapplications/rails.html)

[Here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/packaging_to_executables) are some more recent tools